Nextjs 14 logs undefined error in sentry on Link click
I have a project in Next.js 14 where I added Sentry to capture errors.
Somehow, a strange error is logged in Sentry when I click on a link.
The error looks like this:
Breadcrumbs

Exception - This event
error
09:56:27.000
Error: undefined

Navigation
info
09:56:27.740

{
  from: /route,
  to: /route/subroute
}

Fetch
info
09:56:27.688
GET: https://app.com/route/subroute?_rsc=1pqyf [200]

{
  __span: b5ac28fa601b4aa2
}

I assume it must be something related to Next.js prefetching, given the _rsc query param attached.
Does anyone know anything about this issue?
I tried adding prefetch={false} to the links, but the error is still logged.
